# How to take out variable from JSON request method Android

Tags: android, json, buttonclick

I have a method which takes data from JSON url, which is working fine

```
private void parseJSON() {
...
(some code)
...
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                            String creatorName = response.getString("name");
                                TextView textViewName = findViewById(R.id.text_view_name_detail);
                                textViewName.setText("Creator: "+creatorName);

                            String seeMoreLink = response.getString("see_more_link");


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}
```

BUT... 
I want to take the String seeMoreLink outside the void method, and then give it into the buttonClick method.

```
public void seeMoreClicked (View view)
{
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(seeMoreLink));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

It just don't see seeMoreLink variable outside the json method, and im wondering if it's possible to take out that variable in a simple way (not using List Views, adapter's e.t.c.)

I'm interested in the simpliest way to solve it, and the way in which it should be made (AsyncTask should work i think, but i don't want to make this unless i know that there isn't some simple way with 1 line of code, i tried also putting it into TextView(which is hidden and invisible but app crashes prolly,i should've used thread's in there, but i don't think that making hidden TextView is proper method to use so but maybe im wrong, need opinions from expert's ).

Comment: post your JSON response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Declare a global variable

String link;
```

:

```
     try {
String creatorName = response.getString("name");
TextView textViewName = findViewById(R.id.text_view_name_detail);
textViewName.setText("Creator: "+creatorName);

link = response.getString("see_more_link");


 } catch (JSONException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

and place this method

```
public void seeMoreClicked (View view)
{
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(link));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you my hero ! It is working but, it also starts seeMoreClicked method and it starts automatically when geting JSON strings, how to make it run when i click the button ?